# $H(n)=\lfloor\dfrac{b}{n}\rfloor- \lfloor \dfrac{a}{n} \rfloor=$ (roughly) # odd pairs $o, o+2 \in [a,b]$ such that $n \mid o$ or $n \mid o+2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, inclusion-exclusion, natural-numbers, twin-primes

I came up with the following formula and deleted that question so that I don't have two questions on the same formula.

**Conjecture.** Let $a, b, n \in 2\Bbb{N} + 1$ be odd natural numbers.  Then the formula:

$$
H(a, b, n) = \left \lfloor \dfrac{b}{n} \right \rfloor -\left \lfloor\dfrac{a}{n}\right\rfloor + C(n)
$$

for some function $C: (\Bbb{2\Bbb{N} + 1}) \to \{-1, 0, 1\}$, counts exactly the number of holes punched into the set $P = \{(o, o+2) : o, o+2 \in [a, b]\}$, where by "punches a hole" we mean either $n \mid o$ or $n \mid (o+2)$.

**Question.**  It seems to be true computationally, so what is a formula for computing $C(n)$ that is similar to the formula so far (can use floor, mod, +, -, /, *)?

I tried experimenting with the code to come up with the formula, but that failed, so I'm only posting the code so that you can see apparently $C(n) \in \{-1, 0, 1\}$, but not to "experiment with and find $C(n)$".  What we need to do is a formal analysis based on divisibilty / modular arithmetic, possibly breaking up into modulo cases.

The code:

```
from math import floor, sqrt

N = 50

def actual_count(a, b, n):
    count = 0
        
    for x in range(a, b-1):
        if x % 2 == 1:
            if x % n == 0 or (x+2) % n == 0:
                count += 1
    return count

m = 0
m1 = 0

for a in range(0, N): 
    a = 2*a + 1
    for b in range(0, N):                    
        b = 2*b + 1
        if b >= a + 4:            
            for n in range(1, N):
                n = 2*n + 1
                if n <= sqrt(b):              
                    Hn = floor(b/n) - floor(a/n)
        
                    Cn = actual_count(a,b,n)
                    
                    if Hn - Cn < m1:
                        m1 = Hn - Cn
                    
                    if Hn - Cn > m:
                        m = Hn - Cn
                        
                    print(a, b, n, Hn - Cn)
                    
print (m1, m)
```

seems to always print a min/max of $-1, 1$ at the end of the program, regardless of how high you set $N$ to be.  Hence the conjecture.

---

**Motivation.**

This is related to twin prime counting formulas, so I've tagged with that.  Essentially once you have $H(n) = H(a,b,n)$ you apply the inclusion-exclusion principle so that:

$$
\pi_2(a,b) = \dfrac{b - a}{2} - \sum_{3 \leq q \leq \sqrt{b}} H(q) - \sum_{3 \leq q \lt q' \leq \sqrt{b}} H(qq') + \dots
$$

where the $i$th summation is over all distinct odd prime $i$-tuples with each prime $\leq \sqrt{b}$.  That is easy to see for me since I've been messing around with primes for a while.  I just wanted to mention what this applies to.  So, $\pi_2(a,b)$ counts *exactly* the number of twin prime pairs lying in the interval $[a, b]$.

The next step would be comparing $\pi_2(a, b^2)$ with $\pi_2(a, b^2 + 2b)$ since then the summations in each formula are over the exact same ranges!  So essentially all terms involving $a$ will cancel.  And what you get is an expression related to the inclusion-exclusion formula for $\pi(b^2) - \pi(b) + 1$ which can be found at [Algorithms for evaluating $\pi(x)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Algorithms_for_evaluating_%CF%80(x)).

What should happen is that if the twin primes were finite, then there exists a natural number $N$ such that for all $b \gt a \gt N$ we have an equation involving $\pi(x)$ that will just seem absurd with respect to the prime number theorem's result.

---

By experimenting with the Python code.  The result (for $a = 0$) seems to be:

$$
H(0, b,n) := \lfloor \dfrac{b + n - 2}{n} \rfloor + D(b,n)
$$

where $D(b,n) \in \{0, 1\}$.  This is a lot closer, but still not exact.

---

**Attempt.**  Assuming the solution $C(n)$ takes (and we want it to take) the form $C(n) = \lfloor\dfrac{nX + bY + aZ + W}{n} \rfloor$, we have that the computer can't find coefficients that do the job:

```
from math import floor, sqrt

def hole_actual_count(a, b, n):
    count = 0
    
    for x in range(a, b-2):
        if x % 2 == 1:
            if x % n == 0 or (x + 2) % n == 0:
                count += 1
        
    return count

def rough_hole_estimate(a, b, n):
    return floor((b + n - 2)/n)

def error_in_estimate(a, b, n):
    return hole_actual_count(a, b, n) - rough_hole_estimate(a, b, n)

def error_function_desired_form(X, Y, Z, W, a, b, n):
    return floor((X*a + Y*b + Z*n + W) / n)

N = 20
a = 1

min_soln = (N, N, N, N)
min_solns = []

for X in range(-N, N):
    for Y in range(-N, N):
        for Z in range(-N, N):
            for W in range(-N, N):
                for b in range(0, N):
                    b = 2*b + 1
                    for n in range(1, int(floor(sqrt(b)) / 2) + 1):
                        n = 2*n + 1
                        En = error_in_estimate(a, b, n)
                        
                        if error_function_desired_form(X, Y, Z, W, a, b, n) != En:
                            break
                    else:
                        continue
                    break
                else:
                    soln = (X,Y,Z,W)
                    Xm,Ym,Zm,Wm = min_soln
                    if abs(X*Y*Z*W) < abs(Xm*Ym*Zm*Wm):
                        min_soln = soln
                        min_solns.append(soln)
                        
print(min_solns)
```

prints `[]` since there are no apparent solutions at least with low coefficients.

Comment: I'm at a loss as to how to solve this.  As you can see I've made plenty of attempts.  Please show me the trick :)

Comment: What is $H(a,b,n)$?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the definition of $H(a,b,n)$ correctly. I think that I got $H(0,10,3)=6$. Is this correct?

Comment: @RounakSarkar $H(a,b,n) := $ the definition at the top.  But it counts the number of pairs of odd numbers killed via divisibility by $n$ in either of the pairs entries, all within a given interval $[a,b]$ of naturals.

Comment: Ah, $a,b$ have to be odd. OK, but then (1) why did you consider $H(0,b,n)$ where $a$ is even? (2) why did you include $(5,7),(7,11)$ ? (3) why did you exclude $(7,9),(9,11)$ ? (4) why did you exclude $(1,3),(3,5)$ ?

Comment: @mathlove now you're showing that you understand the formula, because I did miss those, yes $(7,9), (9,11)$ are also in the first set and get cancelled so the total remaining is $6 - 4 = 2$.  You're right!

Comment: Your definition is clear except (4) in my last comment, which I think you have not written in the definition.

Comment: @mathlove You're right yet again.  $H(a,b,n) = 4 = \#\{(1,3),(3,5),(7,9),(9,11)\}$ i.e. the total number "divided by" $n$ where that means $n$ divides either (or logic) component.

Comment: @mathlove With $H(0, b, n)$ I was thinking of computing an absolute count (from zero) and subtracting two of those sort like how integrals work.  Of course that might be a bad idea formula-wise in this scenario, so let's go back to having the endpoints be $a \lt b$ odd numbers.  If you think it's easier with $a = 0,1$ and then subtracting the final two formulas at $b$ from that at $a$, then please show me how that would work in an answer.

Comment: Hint: You have that $\lfloor\frac{b}{n}\rfloor$ counts how many numbers less or equal to $b$ are multiple of $n$. From these you have to subtract those multiple of $2n$ to have only the odd ones, getting $\lfloor\frac{b}{n}\rfloor - \lfloor\frac{b}{2n}\rfloor$. Now if you want only those in $[a,b]$ you have to subtract the count for $a-1$ to get: $\lfloor\frac{b}{n}\rfloor-\lfloor\frac{b}{2n}\rfloor-\lfloor\frac{a-1}{n}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{a-1}{2n}\rfloor$, then continue from there...

Comment: @BillyJoe thank you and I am coding up your formula now to verify it.

Comment: @BillyJoe See answer I made if you want to debug your formula.  It's having larger error values (and they're unbounded) than mathlove's solution.

Comment: Mine was only an hint. Basically you have to multiply by 2 (every odd number belongs to two couples) and then handle the borders. Your code below is wrong: you have to put brackets around 2*n. Then you multiply by 2 and you will have only small errors that you need to fix accounting for borders where a number belongs to one couple only.

Comment: @BillyJoe yes border cases is what I'm having trouble with.  See edits to the code and new error value output.

Comment: @BillyJoe your formula is mostly working, there are some $-1$'s still in the error values, but I'm sure there's some way addressing those.

Comment: @BillyJoe if you can zero out the error and make a brief answer (same as your comment describing your technique), I will select it as the answer, because it's in a more useful form so far (all floor's and all terms very similar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that $\lfloor\frac{b}{n}\rfloor$ counts how many numbers less or equal to b are multiple of $n$. From these you have to subtract those multiple of $2n$ to have only the odd ones, getting $\lfloor\frac{b}{n}\rfloor-\lfloor\frac{b}{2n}\rfloor$. Now if you want only those in $[a,b]$ you have to subtract the count for $a−1$ to get: $\lfloor\frac{b}{n}\rfloor-\lfloor\frac{b}{2n}\rfloor-\lfloor\frac{a-1}{n}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{a-1}{2n}\rfloor$. After this, everything must be multiplied by $2$ because most of those numbers belong to $2$ couples, but we need to subtract the contribution of $a$ and $b$ if these are multiples of $n$: this can be accomplished with $\lfloor\frac{b}{n}\rfloor-\lfloor\frac{b-1}{n}\rfloor$ and $\lfloor\frac{a}{n}\rfloor-\lfloor\frac{a-1}{n}\rfloor$. So we finally get:

$$\begin{aligned} H(a,b,n) &= 2\left(\lfloor\frac{b}{n}\rfloor-\lfloor\frac{b}{2n}\rfloor-\lfloor\frac{a-1}{n}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{a-1}{2n}\rfloor\right)-\lfloor\frac{b}{n}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{b-1}{n}\rfloor-\lfloor\frac{a}{n}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{a-1}{n}\rfloor \\&= \lfloor\frac{b}{n}\rfloor-2\lfloor\frac{b}{2n}\rfloor-\lfloor\frac{a-1}{n}\rfloor+2\lfloor\frac{a-1}{2n}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{b-1}{n}\rfloor-\lfloor\frac{a}{n}\rfloor \end{aligned}$$

Comment: And next time try to finish it yourself ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Let $n\ge 3$.

Let $M$ be the number of odd numbers $m$ such that
$$a\le mn\le b-2$$
Also, $K$ be the number of odd numbers $k$ such that
$$a+2\le kn\le b$$

Then, one has $H(a,b,n)=M+K$.

Now, note that
$$a\le mn\le b-2\iff\left\lceil\frac{a}{n}\right\rceil\le m\le \left\lfloor\frac{b-2}{n}\right\rfloor$$
and
$$a+2\le kn\le b\iff\left\lceil\frac{a+2}{n}\right\rceil\le k\le\left\lfloor\frac{b}{n}\right\rfloor$$

- If $\left\lceil\frac{a}{n}\right\rceil$ is odd and $\left\lfloor\frac{b-2}{n}\right\rfloor$ is odd, then $M=\frac{\left\lfloor\frac{b-2}{n}\right\rfloor-\left\lceil\frac{a}{n}\right\rceil+2}{2}$
- If $\left\lceil\frac{a}{n}\right\rceil$ is odd and $\left\lfloor\frac{b-2}{n}\right\rfloor$ is even, then $M=\frac{\left\lfloor\frac{b-2}{n}\right\rfloor-\left\lceil\frac{a}{n}\right\rceil+1}{2}$
- If $\left\lceil\frac{a}{n}\right\rceil$ is even and $\left\lfloor\frac{b-2}{n}\right\rfloor$ is odd, then $M=\frac{\left\lfloor\frac{b-2}{n}\right\rfloor-\left\lceil\frac{a}{n}\right\rceil+1}{2}$
- If $\left\lceil\frac{a}{n}\right\rceil$ is even and $\left\lfloor\frac{b-2}{n}\right\rfloor$ is even, then $M=\frac{\left\lfloor\frac{b-2}{n}\right\rfloor-\left\lceil\frac{a}{n}\right\rceil}{2}$

Therefore, one can write
$$M=\frac{\left\lfloor\frac{b-2}{n}\right\rfloor-\left\lceil\frac{a}{n}\right\rceil+\frac{1-(-1)^{\left\lfloor\frac{b-2}{n}\right\rfloor}}{2}+\frac{1-(-1)^{\left\lceil\frac{a}{n}\right\rceil}}{2}}{2}$$
i.e.
$$M=\frac{2\left\lfloor\frac{b-2}{n}\right\rfloor-2\left\lceil\frac{a}{n}\right\rceil-(-1)^{\left\lfloor\frac{b-2}{n}\right\rfloor}-(-1)^{\left\lceil\frac{a}{n}\right\rceil}+2}{4}$$

Therefore, one has
$$H(a,b,n)=M+K=\frac{2\left\lfloor\frac{b-2}{n}\right\rfloor-2\left\lceil\frac{a}{n}\right\rceil-(-1)^{\left\lfloor\frac{b-2}{n}\right\rfloor}-(-1)^{\left\lceil\frac{a}{n}\right\rceil}+2}{4}+\frac{2\left\lfloor\frac{b}{n}\right\rfloor-2\left\lceil\frac{a+2}{n}\right\rceil-(-1)^{\left\lfloor\frac{b}{n}\right\rfloor}-(-1)^{\left\lceil\frac{a+2}{n}\right\rceil}+2}{4}$$

Comment: your formula is correct: I had an issue with my `actual_count()` code it was returning $3$ instead of $4$ for your $(1,11,3)$ test case.

Answer (score 0):

@mathlove
The code is now working and has verified your formula (the error is zero!).

```
from math import floor, sqrt, ceil

def hole_actual_count(a, b, n):
    count = 0

    for x in range(a, b-1):
        if x % 2 == 1:
            if x % n == 0 or (x + 2) % n == 0:
                count += 1

    return count

def rough_hole_estimate(a, b, n):
    return M(a,b,n) + K(a,b,n)

def M(a,b,n):
    """
    Thanks @mathlove:
       https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4280856/26327    
    """
    a = ceil(a/n)
    b = floor((b-2)/n)
    return (2*b - 2*a - (-1)**b -(-1)**a +2) / 4

def K(a,b,n):
    return M(a+2, b+2, n)


def error_in_estimate(a, b, n):
    return hole_actual_count(a, b, n) - rough_hole_estimate(a, b, n)

N = 100


for a in range(0, N):
    a = 2*a + 1
    for b in range(0, N):
        if b > a:
            b = 2*b + 1
            for n in range(1, int(floor(sqrt(b)) / 2) + 1):
                n = 2*n + 1
                En = error_in_estimate(a, b, n)            

                print(f"E({a}, {b}, {n}) = {En}")
```

Comment: For example, I got from my formula $H(1,11,3)=4$ which I think is correct.

Comment: @mathlove your formula must be correct.  The code is saying that it appears that way.

Answer (score 0):

**BillyJoe**'s technique:

---

```
from math import floor, sqrt, ceil

def hole_actual_count(a, b, n):
    count = 0
    
    for x in range(a, b-1):
        if x % 2 == 1:
            if x % n == 0 or (x + 2) % n == 0:
                count += 1
        
    return count

def rough_hole_estimate(a, b, n):
    return M(b,n) - K(a,n) + floor((b-1)/n) - floor(a/n)

def M(b,n):
    """
    Thanks @BillyJoe in an MSE comment.
    """
    return floor(b/n) - 2 * floor(b/(2*n))
    
def K(a,n):
    return M(a-1,n)
    

def error_in_estimate(a, b, n):
    return hole_actual_count(a, b, n) - rough_hole_estimate(a, b, n)

N = 1000


for a in range(0, N):
    a = 2*a + 1
    for b in range(0, N):
        if b > a:
            b = 2*b + 1
            for n in range(1, int(floor(sqrt(b)) / 2) + 1):
                n = 2*n + 1
                En = error_in_estimate(a, b, n)            
                
                print(f"E({a}, {b}, {n}) = {En}")
```

Code outputs zero as the error value now, which means exact formula!

Comment: See my comment below the question.

Comment: @BillyJoe there are the new error values.  I put parentheses around `2*n`.

Comment: You must also multiply by 2 the whole formula.

Comment: @BillyJoe Thank you, that did it!

Comment: @BillyJoe see edits.  The errors are now in $\{-1, 0\}$.   Which is really close.  What correction factor must we add?