# Can the prime counting function possibly satisfy this functional equation?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, functional-equations, analytic-number-theory, twin-primes

Let $a,b,n$ be odd natural numbers, $a \gt b$, and $n \gt 1$

Here's a [proof by BillyJoe](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4280920/26327) that the function,

$$h(a,b,n) := 2(\lfloor \dfrac{b}{n} \rfloor  - \lfloor\dfrac{b}{2n} \rfloor - \lfloor \dfrac{a-1}{n} \rfloor + \lfloor \dfrac{a - 1}{2n} \rfloor) - \lfloor\dfrac{b}{n} \rfloor + \lfloor \dfrac{b - 1}{n}\rfloor - \lfloor \dfrac{a}{n}\rfloor + \lfloor \dfrac{a-1}{n}\rfloor
$$

counts exactly, the number of pairs of odd numbers $o, o+2 \in [a, b] \subset \Bbb{N}$ such that either $n \mid o$ or $n \mid o + 2$.

Define the inclusion-exclusion operator:

$$
T(f)(a,b,n) := \sum_{u \mid \frac{p_n\#}{2}} (-1)^{\omega(u)}f(a,b,u) 
$$

Then we have that the total number of twin primes lying in the interval $[X^2, X^4]$ for odd $X$ is:

$$
\pi_2(X^2, X^4) = \dfrac{X^4 - X^2}{2} - T(h)(X^2, X^4)
$$

But if there a a finite number of twin primes, then for all $X \geq N_0 \in \Bbb{N}, X$ odd we have:

$$
0 = \pi_2(X^2, X^4) = \dfrac{X^4 - X^2}{2} - T(h)(X^2, X^4, n)
$$

$T$ applied to $\lfloor \dfrac{b}{n} \rfloor - \lfloor\dfrac{b}{2n} \rfloor$ of course equals $\pi(b) - \pi(\sqrt{b}) + 1$ according to [algorithms for evaluating $\pi(x)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Algorithms_for_evaluating_%CF%80(x)).  Similarly for $a-1$ in place of $b$.

Thus we have that for all $X \geq N_0$ odd:

$$
0 = \dfrac{X^4 - X^2}{2} - 2 (\pi(X^4) - \pi(X^2) + 1 + \pi(X^2 - 1) - \pi(\sqrt{X^2 - 1}) - 1) + T(\text{the rest})(a,b,n) \\
\iff \\
0 = \dfrac{X^4 - X^2}{2} - 2 (\pi(X^4) - \pi(X^2) + \pi(X^2 - 1) - \pi(\sqrt{X^2 - 1})) + T(\text{the rest})(a,b,n) \\
\iff \\
0 = \dfrac{X^4 - X^2}{2} - 2(\pi(X^4) - \pi(\sqrt{X^2 - 1})) + T(\text{the rest})(a,b,n)
$$
since $\pi(X^2 - 1) = \pi(X^2)$ since $X^2 - 1$ is composite for $X \gt 2$.

And $T(\text{the rest})(a,b,n) = \sum_{u \mid \frac{p_{\pi(X^2)}\#}{2}} (-1)^{\omega(u)} (\lfloor\dfrac{b}{n} \rfloor - \lfloor\dfrac{b - 1}{n}\rfloor - \dots)$.

But that just counts each divisor of $\dfrac{p_{\pi(X^2)}\#}{2}$ that also divides $b$ or in other words:

$$T(\text{the rest}) = \sigma_0(\gcd(\dfrac{p_{\pi(X^2)}\#}{2}, X^4)) - \sigma_0(\gcd(\dfrac{p_{\pi(X^2)}\#}{2}, X^2))
$$

---

But clearly, because of the way primorial works with a gcd we must have that $T(\text{rest}) = 0$!

Is it possible that under the prime number theorem, $\pi(X)$ can satisfy this functional equation?

$$
\pi(X^4) - \pi(X) = \dfrac{X^4 - X^2}{4}, \forall X \in 2 \Bbb{N} + 1, X \geq N_0
$$

for some $N_0 \in \Bbb{N}$?

---

We know that $\dfrac{\pi(X^4)}{\pi(X)} \to \dfrac{X^3}{4}$ as $X \to \infty$ viewing $\pi(X)$ as a real function.

How do we reconcile the realness required with the fact the functional equation is only equality necessarily at odd naturals?   Do we use an error term or something? Please demonstrate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question, in short: is there some $N_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
\pi(n^4) - \pi(n) = \dfrac{n^4 - n^2}{4}
$$
for all odd $n$?

The answer is no, for the reason you already gave: it is incompatible with the growth of $\pi(x).$ In particular,
$$
\pi(n^4) - \pi(n) < \dfrac{n^4 - n^2}{4}
$$
for $n\ge4$.

Comment: But how can we prove that?  I've been looking at asymptotics for a few hours and still wondering.  It's not like we can take the limit of the LHS sincee there's no asymptotic property with respect to addition afaik.

Comment: That the answer is "no" follows directly from the asymptotics. (Note that $\pi(n^4) - \pi(n) = O(n^4/\log n),$ you can certainly do asymptotics with addition.) Proving the sharp bound I gave requires more, say, Dusart's bounds on $\pi(x).$

Comment: Do you mean $O(n^4 / \log(n^4))$?

Comment: @AbstractSpacecraft $O(n^4/\log(n^4)) = O(n^4/(4\log n)) = O(n^4/\log n).$ The first is a property of logarithms, the second a property of big-O.